# Custom VCL snippet for fastly is not deployed

Tags: magento2, varnish, magento2-cloud, adobe-commerce, fastly

We are using Adobe Commerce Cloud v2.4.4 - with the fastly extension 1.2.185

In the documention for custom VCL snippets there is [a section for automated custom VCL snippets deployment](https://github.com/fastly/fastly-magento2/blob/master/Documentation/Guides/CUSTOM-VCL-SNIPPETS.md).

We did add our custom snippet `deliver_100_setHttpResponseHeaderXContentTypeOptionsNosniff.vcl` to our git repository - below the path `var/vcl_snippets_custom`.

After performing a deployment to our cloud-environment we expected to find the custom snippet on the server below `~/var/vcl_snippets_custom`.
But the file wasn't there.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got [an answer on Github](https://github.com/fastly/fastly-magento2/issues/576#issuecomment-1260445915) from one of the contributors of this extension: the automated deployment of VCL snippets is currently not supported by the Adobe Cloud deployment process.